# What do the half-reactions need to be for balancing a redox reaction in an acidic medium?

Tags: redox, stoichiometry

> Balance the following reaction:
>   $$\ce{CuS + SO4^{2-} -> CuO + SO2}$$

Below, the number mentioned in the parenthesis is the oxidation number of sulfur.
I have found out that the oxidation half-reactions and reduction half-reactions are as follows:

\begin{align}
\ce{CuS^{(-2)}     &-> ^{(4)}SO2}&& \text{Oxidation half reaction}\\
\ce{^{(6)}SO4^{2-} &-> ^{(4)}SO2}&& \text{Reduction half reaction}
\end{align}

**Problem:**

In this, what about $\ce{CuO}$ in the product side? I have also learned that we need to balance the spectator ions before charges if the spectator ion is other than oxygen and hydrogen.

Here, there is no $\ce{Cu}$ in reduction half reaction. So, I think there is something is wrong in my reduction half-reaction.

Comment: Your "half-reactions" involve the right oxidizer/reducer (oxygen in both cases), but a half-reaction needs to preserve atoms and charges, so you need to try again.  In fact the original equation is just a shorthand -- notice that there are no charges on the left but there on the right, so something is missing. You'll need to add $\ce{H^+}$ on one side and $\ce{H_2O}$ on the other.  Which goes on which side?

Comment: Also, does the problem say you have to use the half-reaction method?  I ask because this method is not the easiest way to solve this problem (again, because O is being both oxidized and reduced).  Completing the equation with $\ce{H^+}$ and water and then comparing coefficients for each type of atom and for the charges will be easier (you might want to introduce an unknown, x, on the left side: $\ce{1 CuS + x \cdot SO4^{2-} + \cdots}$)

Comment: @SilvioLevy i know this is not the good approach but my teacher told you should learn this so i have show him by solving this reaction only by this method :-)

Comment: @SilvioLevy, I don't think oxygen changes oxidation states; it appears to be -2 in all products and reactants. Sulfur, however, is -2 in the sulfide, +6 in the sulfate, but +4 in sulfur dioxide. So, the sulfide is oxidized while the sulfate is reduced.

Comment: @Freddy, almost every sulfur redox reaction I've seen is done in acidic solution. Is that the case here? This is relevant, since the half-reaction methods of balancing equations for acidic and basic solution are different.

Comment: I have done that only take a look at both half reactions. Should i mention oxidation number in it then it will be more easier

Comment: @GregE. yes it is in acidic medium

Comment: @GregE. Of course.  And I wrote it twice no less -- clearly I shouldn't be composing answers this late at night. Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to edit those comments anymore.

Comment: @SilvioLevy, as a fellow insomniac, I sympathize. It's a trivial error.

Comment: @SilvioLevy you know at my place it's still lunch time :-)

Comment: @Freddy I see you've written down the oxidation states now.  Comparing the change in oxidation state in the first "half reaction" with the one in the second, can you figure out how many copies of one half reaction should be combined with how many of the other?

Comment: @SilvioLevy I think 3 copies of 2nd half reaction should be combined with 1st half reaction. after balancing charge, hydrogen and oxygen.

Comment: Perfect.  You're almost done... Now do the balancing and write the answer so we can vote it up!

Comment: @SilvioLevy take a look at the answer if you come through any mistake please inform me. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Freddy - see comment after the solution.  Nice job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below, the number mentioned in the parenthesis is the oxidation number of sulfur.

1. Writing down half reactions:
   \begin{align}
   \ce{CuS^{(-2)}     &-> ^{(4)}SO2}&& \text{Oxidation}\\
   \ce{^{(6)}SO4^{2-} &-> ^{(4)}SO2}&& \text{Reduction}
   \end{align}
2. Adding electrons in both reactions:
   \begin{align}
   \ce{CuS^{(-2)}           &-> ^{(4)}SO2 + 6e-}&& \text{Oxidation}\\
   \ce{^{(6)}SO4^{2-} + 2e- &-> ^{(4)}SO2}&& \text{Reduction}
   \end{align}
3. Balancing $\ce{Cu}$:
   \begin{align}
   \ce{CuS^{(-2)}&-> ^{(4)}SO2 + 6e- + Cu^{+2}}&& \text{Oxidation}
   \end{align}
4. Balancing charges of both half reactions:
   \begin{align}
   \ce{CuS^{(-2)}&-> ^{(4)}SO2 + 6e- +CuO + 6H+}&& \text{Oxidation}\\
   \ce{^{(6)}SO4^{2-} + 2e- +4H+ &-> ^{(4)}SO2}&& \text{Reduction}
   \end{align}
5. Balancing oxygen and hydrogen:
   \begin{align}
   \ce{CuS^{(-2)} + 3H2O&-> ^{(4)}SO2 + 6e- +CuO + 6H+}&& \text{Oxidation}\\
   \ce{^{(6)}SO4^{2-} + 2e- +4H+ &-> ^{(4)}SO2 + 2H2O}&& \text{Reduction}
   \end{align}
6. Adding 3 copies of reduction half reaction with oxidation half reaction, gives finally balanced redox reaction:
   $$\ce{CuS + 3SO4^{2-}  + 6H+ -> 4SO2 +CuO + 3H2O}$$

(Thanks to Silvio Levy for helping me to solve this problem.)